# Why are motocross helmets designed the way they are?

Tags: safety

I can imagine lots and lots of reasons why a MotoGp helmet is desgined that way. Aerodynamics and multiple layers of protection being the main reason. But a motocross helmet has its front pointed. And a sunshade(it seems). How aerodynamic is that anyways? In case if the rider should fall on his/her nose, the long pointed end of the helmet may prove to be counter-productive and it might hurt/break the neck. But i can guess why do they insist on using goggles instead of visors. Is that the reason? That a person can use goggles which fit perfectly inside the MotoCross Helmet?

Answer (score 4):

It's all about safety for the specific requirements of motocross.

In motocross you do not want the weight of a full helmet when you are coming down off a jump, so the lighter the helmet, the less strain on your neck.

- The peak is designed to snap off in the event of a crash, so that is not a problem.
- Aerodynamics are also not an issue - motocross speeds are relatively low.

Comment: I would think the "peak" (I would call it a bill) is there to protect the rider from debris kicked up by other riders.

Comment: That is true - the peak does a bit of that (ie stopping falling debris catching the rider by surprise while they are looking down at the ground)